# Mongodb.aggregate() is ignoring indices

Tags: mongodb

I have collection of archived tasks with roughly following structure

```
{
    "_id" : "job-id_00000001_2017-03-17T21:30:38.510Z",
    "jobId" : "job-id",
    "result" : {
        "status" : "ok"
    },
    "..." : "..."
}
```

On top of that I have indices by

```
jobId: 1
result.status: 1
jobId: 1, result.status: 1
```

In some use cases I need to update statistics rather frequently (map: job-id -> status -> count) and when I execute this aggregation function ...

```
db.getCollection('jobs_archive').aggregate([
            {$group: {
                _id: {jobId: "$jobId", status: "$result.status"},
                count: { $sum: 1 }
            }}
        ], {explain: true} )
```

... it runs ~4sec on 1.2mln of rows and this is unacceptably long. With `explain: true` I get ...

```
"queryPlanner" : {
    "plannerVersion" : 1,
    "namespace" : "db.jobs_archive",
    "indexFilterSet" : false,
    "parsedQuery" : {},
    "winningPlan" : {
        "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
        "direction" : "forward"
    },
    "rejectedPlans" : []
}
```

... and COLLSCAN means that Mongo does not use data from indices nevertheless all of the fields are available in compound index `jobId: 1, result.status: 1`.

Is there way to optimize performance of that `aggregate` query? Am I doing something wrong?

---

(*Addendum triggered by answer from Ori Dar*)

After digging more into docs I've noticed the "Covered Query", the functionality like the one I supposed should be used in that case. It seems it is not.

**Covered Query**
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query

> A covered query is a query that can be satisfied entirely using an
>   index and does not have to examine any documents. An index covers a
>   query when both of the following apply:
>
> - all the fields in the query are part of an index, and
> - all the fields returned in the results are in the same index.
>
> ...
>
> Because the index contains all fields required by the query, MongoDB
>   can both match the query conditions and return the results using only
>   the index.
>
> Querying only the index can be much faster than querying documents
>   outside of the index. Index keys are typically smaller than the
>   documents they catalog, and indexes are typically available in RAM or
>   located sequentially on disk.

---

More weirdness from Mongo

```
(1) db.getCollection('jobs_archive').find({"jobId" : "job-id"}).count()
--> 0.375sec, count = 430000

(2) db.getCollection('archive').find({"jobId" : "job-id", "result.status": "ok"}).count()
--> 1.400sec, count = 430000
```

`explain()` says

1. winningPlan: IXSCAN / "indexName" : "jobId_1_result.status_1"
2. winningPlan: IXSCAN / "indexName" : "jobId_1"

So, I would use 'query().count()' for each combination of 'job-id+status' (it is 6 * 5) if Mongo use indices correctly, but it is seems it is not in this case too. When I specify both keys 'jobId + result.status' compound index is not used for `count()` ... and when I specify only one `jobId` in query, compound index IS used ... r-r-r-r

Note: Mongo "version" : "3.4.2", Ubuntu 16

Answer (score 1):

From [Pipeline Operators and Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#aggregation-pipeline-operators-and-performance)

> > Pipeline Operators and Indexes¶
> >
> > The $match and $sort pipeline operators can take advantage of an index when they occur at the beginning of the pipeline.

MongoDB **won't** use indexes for `$group`

You are doing a full scan, in the sense that all documents are processed. So using the index would have resulted in a duplicate lookup for each document: once for the index and one for the document itself, so what's the point.

Thus, an index can only be used only if you narrow down the results by using a `$match` filter first.

As a side note, the `{jobId: 1}` index is redundant.

The query optimizer can use the `{jobId: 1, result.status: 1}` index for queries using the following  pattern: `db.jobs_archive.find({jobId: n})`

See [Prefixes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/#prefixes)

Comment: Why do you think *'MongoDB won't use indexes for $group'*? I looked through their docs and did not find such statement. Instead I've found note about 'Covered Query' (see addendum in my question) - and this is exactly my case, but it seems it does not work for some reason.

Comment: Because the statement I've quoted from the reference documentation says exactly so. And you are not using covered queries. For using covered queries you have to `$match` on the exact index fields and exclude the _id field as well

Comment: Run something like `db.jobs_archive.explain().aggregate({$match: {jobId: 1}},{$group: {_id: {jobId: "$jobId", status: "$result.status"}, count: { $sum: 1 }}})` and you will see the index in action

Comment: Your quote from docs relates only to `$match` and `$sort`, it does not relate to `$group`. To aggregate a 'doc' Mongo needs to fetch it, since all fields needed are already in the compound index - Mongo may use it as mentioned in `Covered Queries`. `$match` is actually useless to me because I need aggregation over entire collection. Your query indeed says it will IXSCAN for `$match`, but I need no `$match` - jsut for test adding `{$match: {jobId: {"$exists":"true"}}}` result in 8sec of execution time instead of 4s I already have

Comment: *For using covered queries you have to ...*  I think `$project` is more appropriate here - `{$project: {jobId: 1, "result.status": 1}}` - does not help actually ... i afraid Mongo developers just missed such use-case.